# How to create a virtual file for output?

Tags: python, io, in-memory, virtual-file

I need to create a virtual file in memory to trick the system and to let it think that it exists.

I have some scientific program and I heed to provide in some function file for output as argument.

I want to create some file in memory and provide this file to this function.

I do not want to use some temp folders and so on.
How do you think, is it possible to create this trick?

Answer (score 2):

The [`io`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) library can create in-memory file like objects that act like file handles opened with the typical `f = open(filename, mode)`. If you would have opened in normal text mode, a [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o) should do the trick, or if you would have opened the file in binary mode, [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) is the way to go.

Comment: Also [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tempfile.html) library provides (as it's name suggests) a temporary file-like object.

Comment: unfortunately that does not help. I already tried this before opening a question. It returns empty string. Also for test I tried output.write('test') and getvalue() returned me a result. But when I provide output as an argument to this function outpus is still empty.

Comment: @BeliaevMaksim what is this function you need to provide a file for? Given the description in your comment, you must have a problem elsewhere then.

Comment: @Aaron, I need to provide a file with path as argument.

Comment: @BeliaevMaksim then the function itself is taking care of opening the file and writing to it. You either need to edit the function itself, or [mount a section of system ram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive) as a logical volume to create the file on.

Comment: @Aaron, I think smth like second idea. Is there any chance to make it simple ?

Comment: @BeliaevMaksim ramdisks are not super standardized across operating systems. Ultimately it's usually managed by an external program rather than being a feature built into the OS. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software) has a list of existing ramdisk software packages sorted by OS.